# How to stop breaking javascript imports to new lines in Atom editor

Tags: atom-editor, atom-beautify

I'm using Atom editor. In my Vue files, I sometimes use `import` statements. For example:

```
<script>
import { get } from 'lodash';

export default {
  data () {
    return {};
  }
};
</script>
```

Whenever I save the file, Atom breaks the `import` statement to multiple lines:

```
<script>
import {
  get
} from 'lodash';

export default {
  data () {
    return {};
  }
};
</script>
```

Does anyone know what setting is causing this to happen? If I go into the settings for "Atom Beautify", and I disable the Vue language, the line is no longer broken up when saved. So it clearly has something to do with this "Atom Beautify" package, but I can't figure out what setting is causing it.